# geth --dev mining

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethereumjs, console

Newbie here.

I ran `geth --dev` and then `geth --dev attach` on another console and everything is looking fine.

When I run `miner.start()` I can see on my `geth --dev` window that there are some blocks being mined...

**What does this mean?** what blocks am I mining if I'm the only one in the network? when I run `geth --dev` dont I need to sync a blockchain?(I guess there isn't one since I just created it on the provate network but the first question still persists)

Any pointers/tutorials on geth commands/deeper explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to geth --help, the --dev option puts you in "Developer mode: pre-configured private network with several debugging flags". You are running a private network of your own.

FWIW I spent a few days trying to figure out from the docs how to get started and summarised my own newbie findings here - may help https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/first-steps-with-ethereum-private-networks-and-smart-contracts-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Nice guide! but still i am looking for the answer as to what exactly/how is that mining being configured. If I were to run geth on testnet and mine then Im guessing I would be mining blocks of people that are on the testnet... but not sure on dev

Comment: geth --dev is running your own private network.

Comment: what about geth --rpc?

Comment: It enables you to connect to the geth node via RPC, e.g. see this wiki page https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console  
  
Specifically the example command:  
  
    curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_start","params":[],"id":74}' localhost:8545  
  
 .... What is it you are actually looking to do here?

Comment: Just wanted to understand more about the whole process. Thanks though!